# Failed to locate manager object freezing Fedora

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I'm using Fedora 29. I had to reinstall it, but I kept a backup of all my folders. After the installation, I booted up in Ubuntu (dual boot) and copied and replaced all the backup files (including the etc folder, and usr, etc). I then booted from Fedora 29 and I get this error:

[image]

I tried to boot in rescue mode and I get the same thing:

[image]

I googled it, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: But why did you copy the old /usr and /etc? That almost completely defeats the point of reinstalling the OS, it's like reinstalling Windows and then copying the old C:\Windows on top of it.

Comment: Looking in /etc for different files between the backup and a fresh  install might spot the odd config file you want to keep...

Comment: Yes, It does defeat the purpose of a new install...almost. I had to re-install because I had disk encryption, complex issue, but the re-installation fixed it. I copied all the files, not just the etc and usr. I did this so as not to have to reconfigure and re-install everything. Replying to your second comment, I'm not that good yet, so I don't know what got changed and what didn't, so I just copied everything.